# feed rrs don't use ssl

Tags: https, feed

please see that "https://www.arwikig.com/feeds/posts/default" Even though feeds link is use https all Posts inside use http   any one can help me I want any way to make feeds with https bcz now links in google with http Even though site with https

Comment: please any one can help me ?

Comment: Please explain what you tried...add some code, show examples and explain the problem. This is not a code request forum.